# PDOException while installation in M2

Tags: magento2.1.5, magento2-enterprise

```
[ERROR] exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`m2mar1317`.`cms_page`, CONSTRAINT `CMS_PAGE_PAGE_ID_SEQUENCE_CMS_PAGE_SEQUENCE_VALUE` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `sequence_cms_page` (`sequence_value`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

How to fix this issue?

Attached screenshot:
[image]

Comment: how are you installing M2?

Comment: not through composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed after contacting magento support. 
The default dB table engine should be InnoDB and mine was MyISAM, and as a result, causing this error.

To change the default DB engine in `/etc/my.cnf` set the following:

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

instead of

```
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

After making these changes, installation went successful.